# Как сделать с помощью flexbox такую пирамидку?

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать с помощью flexbox такую пирамидку? Предполагаю что можно с помощью гридов, но они не подходят

```
.apartaments-filter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    &__item {
        width: 20%;
        height: 60px;
        border: 2px solid #f6f6f6;
        border-right: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Оформите код текстом, а не картинкой пожалуйста

Comment: `.apartaments-filter {justify-content: center}`

Answer (score 1):

Решение на Flexbox, где родителю задаётся `flex-wrap: wrap`, а дочерним элементам `width: 33.33%`:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.list .item {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.list .item:nth-child(3) {
  border: 0;
  background: #07f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Показать все</div>
  <div class="item">От 20-30 млн</div>
  <div class="item">От 30-50 млн</div>
  <div class="item">От 50-100 млн</div>
  <div class="item">Более 100 млн</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pyramid-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    margin: 100px 0;
}

.pyramid-item {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 33.33333%;

    border: 3px solid red;
}

.flex-3 {
    border-left: 0;
}

.flex-3:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}

.flex-2 {
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

.flex-2:last-child {
    border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```
<div class="pyramid">
    <div class="pyramid-inner">
        <div class="pyramid-item flex-3"></div>
        <div class="pyramid-item flex-3"></div>
        <div class="pyramid-item flex-3"></div>
        <div class="pyramid-item flex-2"></div>
        <div class="pyramid-item flex-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```